# Erro: Mcrypt required no Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, mcrypt

Fiz uma nova instalação do Laravel 4. Tenho todos os requerimentos do sistema estão corretos. Porém, quando tento usar o `artisan` pra rodar o comando `key:generate`, para configurar minha APP, não consigo. Me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Mcrypt PHP extension required

Como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você deve instalar a extensão mcrypt, que normalmente não é inclusa com o PHP.

Não sei qual seu sistema operacional, aqui seque o modelo para alguns, se você ajudar informando qual é o sistema, posso ser mais específico:

**Debian/Ubuntu**:

> apt-get install php5-mcrypt

**OS X via HomeBrew**:

> brew install php55-mcrypt

**Windows**:

a extensão deve não estar ativa, descomente a linha

> ;php_mcrypt.dll

em seu **php.ini** removendo o **;** do início, deixando assim:

> php_mcrypt.dll

Depois, reinicie seu servidor!

Comment: Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt. Resolvido o problema.

Comment: você pode marcar a resposta como correta então...

Answer (score 0):

**Debian/Ubuntu**

```
//Cria um link para mods-available    
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available

//Habilita o mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt 
//Reinicia o apache
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, é necessário realizar a instalação da biblioteca `Mcrypt`
Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install php53-mcrypt ou php54-mcrypt
```

Ir no arquivo `php.ini` descomentar a lib `php_mcrypt.so`

No OSX: (e preciso ter o homebrew instalado)

```
brew install php53-mcrypt ou php54-mcrypt
```

> Observação: Caso ele não encontre o pacote, o homebrew procura por uma alternativa e mostra caso encontre um repositório para fazer download. Basta ou adicionar o repositório ou simplesmente escrever da forma que foi passado no brew install que ele deve instalar certo. Também talvez ele necessite instalar ao zlib que não tem no repositório ao tentar instalar pelo brew porem ele ira informar um repositório que pode ser utilizado.

O homebrew pode não instalar por falta de outras bibliotecas que necessitam ser adicionadas a parte, basta procurar no google por brew e o nome da biblioteca.
Após instalar deve ir em:

```
cd /private/etc
sudo mv php.ini.default php.ini
sudo {editor de preferencia} php.ini
```

Dentro do arquivo adicionar nas extensões:

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php53-mcrypt/5.3.28/mcrypt.so"
```

Modifique a versão conforme sua necessidade, e reiniciar o apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

No Windows, vai depender se vc esta utilizando algum bundle como o wamp. Neste e preciso definir as bibliotecas que devem ficar ativas para o php.

Talvez este link ajude a configurar para o wamp:
    [configurar wamp para mcrypt](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/laravel-requires-mcrypt-php-extension-4419933.S.5811363156064219140)
e [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Laravel-Framework-in-Windows)